# The intern method in java string is different for the STRING CONNECT

Tags: java, string

I find that the intern method in java string is different for the STRING CONNECT. I am using the JDK 1.8.0_45

```
public class LocalTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

       String s1 = new String("hell") + new String("o");
       String s2 = s1.intern();
       System.out.println("s1 == s2? " + (s1 == s2));

    }
}
//s1 == s2? true
```

But when using the following, the output is false

```
public class LocalTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

           String s1 = new String("hello");
           String s2 = s1.intern();
           System.out.println("s1 == s2? " + (s1 == s2));

    }

}//s1 == s2? false
```

I know there is some optimization in the JVM but I am not sure where it is.

Thank you.

Comment: `new` goes to heap and literals goes to string pool. So they should have different references. If you have tried `==` then will return `false` since it compares the reference.

Comment: But it can not explain the "true" case.

Comment: In the first example `s1` becomes a literal due to the *concatenation* and goes to string pool.

Comment: @sura2k `s1` is absolutely *not* a literal--this entire construction ensures it. It's only a literal when you have explicit inline concatenation of string constants.

Comment: @chrylis yes... should be declared statically within ""

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, a string with the value `"hello"` does not exist anywhere in the JVM until you create one via concatenation, and so when you call `intern()` that newly-created string is added to the string pool and returned, and its reference is saved in `s2`.

In the second case, however, `"hello"` is already in the string pool, because all string constants are. You create a new object to save into `s1`, but since the pool already has a copy, when you call `intern()`, the existing pool copy is returned and saved in `s2`, meaning that `s1` and `s2` do not refer to the same object.

Comment: That does not explain why the first test case returns `true`.

Comment: @ammoQ It absolutely does--*the actual object* in `s1` is interned.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks.